# Adding dropdown menu for QGIS Plugin to the toolbar

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have set some actions for my plugin and now I want to group all of them in a dropdown menu as one of the image, which is from another plugin. I've been struggling but I can't find a way to do it like that.

[image]

I have tried this:

```
    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/udt_plugin/icon.png'
        self.action1 = QAction(QIcon(icon_path), u"Action 1", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action2 = QAction(QIcon(icon_path), u"Action 2", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action3 = QAction(QIcon(icon_path), u"Action 3", self.iface.mainWindow())

        self.popupMenu = QMenu(self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.popupMenu.addAction(self.action1)
        self.popupMenu.addAction(self.action2)
        self.popupMenu.addAction(self.action3)

        self.toolButton = QToolButton()

        self.toolButton.setMenu(self.popupMenu)
        self.toolButton.setDefaultAction(self.action1)
        self.toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        self.iface.addToolBarWidget(self.toolButton)
```

But it creates a more simple dropdown menu like below, which is not exactly what I want. I'm using QGIS 3.10.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "simple"? same icons, down arrow?

Comment: Yes, I want that my plugin button has a down arrow which opens a dropdown menu, like in the first image.

Comment: Change the icon to a down arrow :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
self.toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)
```

to

```
self.toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.MenuButtonPopup)
```

[image]